# Speech Recognizer Sound

Tags: java, android, audio, android-intent, speech-recognition

I am using the Speech Recognizer Intent to take User Input and translate it into text. However I want the Intent to continuously take user input and translate it into text to see if the user and said a certain word. My Code is able to do that, but every time my app begins listening for input, the phone makes a short beep sound that it is ready for input.

I was wondering if there is any way to delete the sound from playing every time the recognizer is ready to listen again.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

       //private TextView mText;
       private SpeechRecognizer sr;
       private static final String TAG = "MyStt3Activity";
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                ToggleButton speakButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.CarMode);     
                //mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);     
                speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
                sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());        
       }

       class listener implements RecognitionListener          
       {
                public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
                {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
                }
                public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
                {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
                }
                public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
                {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
                }
                public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
                {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
                }
                public void onEndOfSpeech()
                {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
                }
                public void onError(int error)
                {
                         Log.d(TAG,  "error " +  error);
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "What was that?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         sr.cancel();
                         speechIntent();
                }
                public void onResults(Bundle results)                   
                {
                         //String str = new String();
                         Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
                         ArrayList<String> data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         sr.cancel();
                         speechIntent();
                         //mText.setText("results: "+String.valueOf(data.size()));        
                }
                public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
                {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
                }
                public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
                {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
                }
       }
       public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.CarMode) 
                {
                    speechIntent();
                }
       }

       public void speechIntent()
       {
           Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"com.example.freestyleandroid");

                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5); 
                         sr.startListening(intent);
                         Log.i("111111","11111111");
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you. Add this to your `RecognitionListener.onReadyForSpeech()` method.

```
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
```

Comment: Has a better solution come along for this? While it "works" to mute the sound, it also mutes the entire stream. It is a bit "hacky" after 4 years.